# How to pass an array from server control to a .js file?

Tags: c#, javascript, ascx

How can I pass an array to a .js file from ascx code behind file? 
I have tried using this code in the code behind file of the ascx to pass the parameter to the .js file but The function on .js file (showKendoLetter) is not accessed using ‘ page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript’  method. If anyone knows other methods to execute .js function by passing an array to the function. please help

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    GetType(),
    "var",
    Controls_kendoLetter.showKendoLetter('"+letterTemplate.TemplateText + "');", 
    true);
```

Thanks,

Comment: "it is not working" - worst error description ever ([Here is how to improve](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", "student = {Name: \"something\", Age: 20}", true);
```

by this, `student` is set on `window` object, and you can access it from `javascript`